# Spring RestController method returns status 403

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a RestController with such a code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@CrossOrigin
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping("registration")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void registration(@RequestBody @Valid RegistrationRequest registrationRequest,
                             BindingResult result) {

        //business logic
    }
}
```

I expect to get a response with no body and status code 200.What I get is status 403 - Forbidden.

P.S. When I change this method to return some not null Object, I get status 200 (without @ResponseStatus).

P.P.S. CSRF is disabled

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you added spring security or any filter to your project?

Comment: What is logged on the console?

Comment: @MadhuBhat Yes, I do have Spring Security. This request goes under permitAll().
There is no information logged during this request

Comment: You are getting 403 due to spring security's auth. Can you show me your security config and filter? Would be better if you can provide a github link to your code if possible.

Comment: So, problem was in auth filter. Many thanks to @MadhuBhat

Comment: Great. Happy to be of help. Could you please add the answer and accept it for others' reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in auth filter (setting status 403 was hardcoded...).

Comment: Please add what exactly the problem was. Otherwise this answer would not be useful to anybody else.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below :

- Remove `@RequestMapping("/")` from your controller class
- Modify the annotation on your `registration` method to `@PostMapping("/registration")`
- Make sure that within your security config class (the one you have annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity`) overrides a `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method with `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST, "/registration").permitAll()`. Make sure that you have not disabled CORS here, since you have added `@CrossOrigin` on your controller.

Comment: It didn't help. And, as I've written before, if I change this method to return some data, it works correct. So, as I see it, the problem is^ that it's not working correctly with void. And I don't know how to fix it